# Is there an MRAN (R package snapshot) equivalent for python libraries?

Tags: python

I currently use MRAN snapshots to help maintain some my R enviroments, which are clones of the CRAN R package repository throughout different times in history. This way I can make sure all the package/dependencies are in sync and I can have reproducible results.

Here is a link -> https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility

I also maintain different versions of python and was wondering if something like this existed for python. I currently just do `conda install numpy` but I realized that eventually the dependencies can get out of sync.

Any recommendations or thoughts?

Comment: do you mean file `requirements.txt` with list of all needed modules and and its version? ie. `numpy==1.21.5`, and later you can do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install them on server? And you create this file `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ?